# My data from my loop is being mismatched, not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement

I have a code that is suppose to display messages back and forth between the users. For some reason the data is mismatching and I'm not sure where in my code I have the error. I've tried to change my if statements of `$x < $sender` but that didn't work.

[image: 1]

but the data being displayed doesn't line up with the database information.

[image: 2]

"Test 2" message was sent from woof3, so it should be green and not blue when logged in as woof. And "test again" was sent from woof, so it should be blue when logged in as woof

Edit working code down below, no pdo because I'm not done with this project and I save those for the end to make testing easier.

```
<?php

include "../Site/db.php";

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlArray = explode('=', $url);
$Username = $urlArray[sizeof($urlArray) - 1];

$Myself = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY `Id` ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Header of message box
echo '<div id="messages" class="messagePersonBox shadow">
        <span class="usersname" name="receiver"><a href="Account?='.$Username.'">'.$Username.'</a></span>
<hr style="margin-top:24px">
<div id="allMessages"class="allMessages">
';

// $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE Sender = '$Myself' ORDER BY `Id` ASC";
// $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

$sql3 = "SELECT *  FROM messages 
        WHERE (Sender = '$Myself' AND Receiver = '$Username')
           OR (Receiver = '$Myself' AND Sender = '$Username') ORDER BY `MessageTime` ASC";


$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
print_r($result3);
$x = 0;

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE Sender = '$Myself'";
$result4 = $conn->query($sql4);

$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE Receiver = '$Myself'";
$result5 = $conn->query($sql5);

$totalSender = mysqli_num_rows($result4);
$totalReceiver = mysqli_num_rows($result5);

// might have to add both totals for while loop
// to get total messages
$totalmessages = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// For receiving
while ($x < $totalmessages) {

    // output data of each row

     if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
         if ($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
             $Sender = $row['Sender'];
             $Message = $row['Message'];
             $Receiver = $row['Receiver'];
             $TimeSent = $row['MessageTime'];
         }
     }
       $class = $Sender == $Myself ? 'messageDisplay' : 'messageDisplay2';


     // sending a message

         echo '<div id="messages2" class="'.$class.'">'.$Message.'<span style="float: right;margin-top:2px"><font size=1>'.time_elapsed_string($TimeSent).'</span></font></div>';



$x++;
}

// Typing part of message
echo '</div>
      <input type="text" id="messagetosend" name="message" class="messagetype" placeholder="Type a message..."><span id="send" class="messageSend">↩</span>

</div>';
?>
```

I can add more info if needed.

Comment: Your `conversationID` is not neccesarily unique. What if you get two users called `woo` and `f3woof` chatting? That could give them the same conversation ID as `woof` and `woof3`. Also doing `$Username$Myself` will be inverted when the other part logs in.

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN` instead, rather than using so many queries?

Comment: @Qirel the conversationID was kind of last minute add to just test this so I didn't need to have two different queries. The other two queries (sql4 and 5) are to just count the messages sent and messages received. , will using Join fix my issue with the data being mismatched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a step back and restructure this approach a bit.

For instance, you don't need `conversationID` (at least not in its current format), as you can deduct it from `Sender` and `Receiver`, which is more accurate. You also don't need `MessageDate`, since `MessageTime` is a datetime value that holds both the date and the time. So, `conversationID` and `MessageDate` can be removed.

Then, we can clean up the number of queries. You want to get all messages where you are the sender and the other user is the recipient, *or* where you are the recipient and the other user is the sender of that message. We then sort by date (not the ID!), and check if the message should be green or blue based on the `Sender` value of that row - set a `$class` variable with one value for blue if the sender is the current user, green otherwise.

As a note, when outputting blocks of HTML, you can exit PHP, which makes it easier to read (and deal with quotes). You also had HTML elements with the same ID, which is not allowed.

You should also be using prepared statements when dealing with variables in a query.

```php
<?php

include "../Site/db.php";

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlArray = explode('=', $url);
$Username = $urlArray[sizeof($urlArray) - 1];

$Myself = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql = "SELECT Message, MessageTime, Sender, Receiver
        FROM messages 
        WHERE (Sender = ? AND Receiver = ?)
           OR (Receiver = ? AND Sender = ?)
        ORDER BY `MessageTime` ASC");
if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    error_log($conn->error);
    die("An error occurred fetching messages");
}
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Myself, $Username, $Myself, $Username);
$stmt->bind_result($message, $timeSent, $sender, $received);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    error_log($stmt->error);
    die("An error occurred fetching messages");
}
?>
<!-- Header of message box -->
<div id="messages" class="messagePersonBox shadow">
    <span class="usersname" name="receiver"><a href="Account?=<?php echo $Username; ?>"><?php echo $Username; ?></a></span>
    <hr style="margin-top:24px">
    <div id="allMessages" class="allMessages">
        <?php 
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $class = $sender == $Myself ? 'messageDisplay' : 'messageDisplay1'; // Check which class should be used; if I'm the sender, show messageDisplay, if not show MessageDisplay1 
            ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>
                <?php echo $message; ?>
                <span style="float: right; margin-top: 2px">
                    <?php echo time_elapsed_string($timeSent); ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
    <!-- Typing part of message -->
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="messagetosend" name="message" class="messagetype" placeholder="Type a message..."><span id="send" class="messageSend">↩</span>
</div>
<?php 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: thanks for being helpful and providing the useful tip about the prepared statements, I'll make sure to do that from now on. I got an error of this ` Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\Xammp\htdocs\SocialMedia\Admin\Users\message.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\Xammp\htdocs\SocialMedia\Site\Account.php(890): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Xammp\htdocs\SocialMedia\Admin\Users\message.php on line 17` and i'm not sure what this means since I've never really used a prepared statement

Comment: It means that `$stmt`  is false, because the query failed. See my revised code for catching those errors (then check your error-logs).

Comment: when doing `$sql = "SELECT Message, MessageTime, Sender, Receiver
        FROM messages 
        WHERE (Sender = 'woof' AND Receiver = 'woof3')
           OR (Receiver = 'woof' AND Sender = 'woof3')
        ORDER BY `MessageTime` ASC)"; ` it still comes out as false despite literally being the same values. I trimmed whitespace before entering the data into the database because i had that issue earlier. when coding this.

Comment: Like I said, check your error-logs (now after the addition of `error_log()`), they are much more helpful. Leave the question-marks in the query, and you get the actual error message.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm using this code as a separate file and then doing it php include for it so there is a conflict with the code on the two files.

Comment: Just check the error-logs, then you can stop guessing what's wrong! :D

Comment: Thank you so much, although i didnt use much of your code since it wasn't working, I did use the sql statement and what you taught me is the ` $class = $Sender == $Myself ? 'messageDisplay' : 'messageDisplay2';` that is completely new to me and it helped. I'll update my question with finalized code. I didn't do PDO statement because I usually save those for the end of my projects. Thanks!!!

Comment: I would really advise that you get the error and use the approach suggested in my answer instead. You currently have many queries within a loop, which is really bad performance - and you're not preventing SQL injection. PDO is a library like `mysqli`, not the prepared statement (which you should use!).